# how to set sender_name for the controller Resetting in FOSUserBundle?

Tags: email, symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to change the name of the `sender_name` of the email during the **resetting**.
I already have done this while **registration** and it was successful. 
This was done easily by defining `fos_user.registration.confirmation.from_email.sender_name`.

Now, I am wondering to do the same thing for **resetting**, but no email was sent.
If I delete the configuration of **resetting** *(as seen below)*, the email is sent!

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Minn\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: minn_user_registration 
        confirmation:
            enabled:    true 
            template:   MinnUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig        
            from_email:
                address: %the_address%
                sender_name: %the_name% 
    resetting:
        token_ttl: 86400
        email:
            from_email:
                address:        %the_address%
                sender_name:    %the_name% 
    service:
        mailer:  fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
```

So, any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found!

I just forgot to specify `fos_user.resetting.form.*` as seen below...

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Minn\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: minn_user_registration 
        confirmation:
            enabled:    true 
            template:   MinnUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig        
            from_email:
                address: %the_address%
                sender_name: %the_name% 
    resetting:
        token_ttl: 86400
        email:
            from_email:
                address:        %the_address%
                sender_name:    %the_name% 
        form:
            type:               fos_user_resetting
            name:               fos_user_resetting_form
            validation_groups:  [ResetPassword, Default]  
    service:
        mailer:  fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
```

Hope it will help others...