# FOS Disable Single Password Request Functionality

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using the FOS user bundle in Symfony and I really dont like the fact that a user can only request their password 1 time in 24 hours. Is there any way to disable this feature to enable the user the ability to request their password multiple times. I mean what happens if their reset email never reaches their inbox and they cannot reset the pw again, whats the best way to handle this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In FOSUserBundle configuration exists parameter `token_ttl` which have default value 86400. This is a number of seconds and It is used to determine the time to live for the token and the time the user must wait before retrying the request.

You can try to set 0 or false, it should work.

```
fos_user:
  resetting:
    token_ttl: 0
```

Comment: Actually one more thing if you could, when the reset email is sent it is coming from "webmaster", is there anyway to change this?

Comment: found this actually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25980145/how-to-set-sender-name-for-the-controller-resetting-in-fosuserbundle

Comment: This answer is no longer valid. If you set token_ttl  to 0, as it's now also the expiration token it will immediately expire and not be valid anymore. For more on this matter: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1231

Comment: @xDaizu I know it's been a while since you commented on this, but have you seen any updates/fixes for this?

Comment: @chrislebaron nothing has been implemented yet (as you can read in the linked GitHub issue), but you can still use the workaround in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I found an issue with the below changes to the config.yml

app/config/config.yml

```
fos_user:
  resetting:
     token_ttl: 0
```

This will allow the user to request a new password as many times as they wish (no 24 hour limit) however due to the zero 'time to live' of the token it will automatically reroute you from

```
/resetting/reset/{token}
```

to

```
resetting/request
```

So the user will never be actually given the option to change their password.

This was tested on Symfony 2.6

Answer (score 2):

Long ago, you could just  configure this in `config.yml`

```
fos_user:
  resetting:
    token_ttl: 0
```

but in recent versions, since the token_ttl is **both** the *retry time* and the *lifetime* of the token, if you set it to 0, as soon as you create it, it expires.

You can follow the [issue in Github](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1231)

---

If you need it fixed ASAP, as a **hacky workaround**, you can implement the `resetAction()` by copy-pasting `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Controller/RegistrationController.php` in your AppBundle (or whatever bundle, doesn't really matter) and make the router point to your overriden function, like this (routing.yml):

```
fos_user_resetting_reset:
    path:     /resetting/reset/{token}
    defaults: {_controller: AcmeUserBundle:Resetting:reset }
```

Now, in your `resetAction()` method you can comment out this lines:

```
//        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
//            return $event->getResponse();
//        }
```

There are less hacky ways, of course, like creating your own listener but... this is how I *quickly and dirtily* did it, since I was in a hurry and I already had the resetAction overriden.